# Why does import mechanize break my aws ec2 elastic beanstalk flask "hello world" python app?

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, mechanize

I was able to get to "hello world" using [this nice tutorial](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/create_deploy_Python_flask.html) for setting up ec2 and flask.

Here is my `application.py`:

```
import flask
#import mechanize

application = flask.Flask(__name__)

#Set application.debug=true to enable tracebacks on Beanstalk log output.
#Make sure to remove this line before deploying to production.
application.debug=True

@application.route('/')
def hello_world():
    return "Hello world!"

if __name__ == '__main__':
    application.run(host='0.0.0.0', debug=True)
```

uncommenting `import mechanize` causes Internal Server Error 500

```
Internal Server Error

The server encountered an internal error or misconfiguration and was unable to complete your request.

Please contact the server administrator at root@localhost to inform them of the time this error occurred, and the actions you performed just before this error.

More information about this error may be available in the server error log.
```

in the console on aws ec2, i can indeed run python and import mechanize.

there is a file called requirements.txt that I needed to make in the tutorial.  could this be relate to my problem?  do I need to modify this?

```
Flask==0.9
```

**EDIT:**
I realized something.  I installed mechanize through sudo pip install mechanize, while logged in to ec2.  I can indeed import mechanize from the python command line after this.  I just realized, on the other hand, that I can not import flask on the python command line.

This is puzzling and obviously related to my misunderstanding.

flask was working previously on the web page, and used to display my "hello world", but somehow it is not installed on ec2 command line via python when i log in.  thus, there is a difference between packages available through the web python and the python on the ec2 console.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your python runtime environment maybe different between python console and your app.  Try to print out sys.path and compare the difference.  sys.path is initialized to PYTHONPATH.  So you may need to fix/append to this environment variable.